# Inserting data in key value pairs in dataset angularjs javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting data from factory in my controller. Data being returned is working fine. When I try to insert the data in new dataset array of key value pair, it is not working...

```
var dataset=[];

    $scope.total=hours_repository.getHrs.query({id:wId}, function(data){

         for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
          {
           dataset.push({key: 'data'+i,
                         values: data[i] 
          });
    });
```

My goal is to make dataset look like following...

```
$scope.dataset={
       data1: data[1],
       data2: data[2],
       data3: data[3]
     }
```

However, the way I am pushing in the dataset is not working. 
Please let me know how to fix so that dataset has key values as shown above. 
Thanks

Comment: `I != i` and what you are showing is an object not an array. Please use your browser console to check for errors ... they are great clues to your problems. Also where is `dataset` defined?

Comment: Sorry it was typo. Code is working fine just not pushing values as i want.

Comment: So you want object not array .... can't push to an object, have to define property and value

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataset = {};
...

         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
           dataset['data' + i] = data[i];
         }
...

$scope.dataset = dataset;
```